# Python: Bug in writing a transpose function using lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have an assignment to do, which is:

Write a function transpose which takes in a matrix and transposes it. Basically, this converts a m x n matrix into a n x m matrix.

I wrote a code which seems sensible, but it doesnt get me the result I want. Can anyone point out what is wrong with my code?

```
def transpose(matrix):
    new_matrix=[[]]*len(matrix[0])
    for row in matrix:
        i=0
        for j in row:
            new_matrix[i]+=[j]
            i+=1
    return new_matrix
```

Test case:

```
print(transpose([[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]))
```

Comment: Duplicate the original matrix, loop over i,j and keep doing `new[j][i] = original[i][j]`

Comment: `[list(i) for i in zip(*a)]` try this. this will transpose your matrix.

Comment: Found a dupe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807026/initialize-a-list-of-objects-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize a list of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807026/initialize-a-list-of-objects-in-python)

Comment: Is there other methods other than zip, dont think its expected of me to use zip?

@UbdusSamad How would u predetermine the dimensions of the new matrix? 

I tried it with 2 ranges and it gives me Index Error: index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `*` to multiply some values in a list-initialisation, be careful. You might end up with references that point multiple times to the same value:

```
l = [ [] ]*3
print(l)

l[1].append(34)  # change only "the first" list by appending smth
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], []]
[[34], [34], [34]]  # they are all "the same data" reference
```

---

There is an built-in [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) that does exactly your transposing:

```
l = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] 


l_t = [ list(x) for x in zip(*l)]  # one-line solutions for transposing ;)

print(l)
print(l_t) # transposed
```

Zip has the limitation that it only works to the length of the smallest sublists - yours are all equal so all is fine.

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

If you ever need a zip that takes the longest list, [`itertools.zip_longest(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) can be used, it takes a default param that is substituted for any shorter list-items that are not there.

Btw. just `list(zip(l))` looks like this: `[(1,5,9),(2,6,10),(3,7,11),(4,8,12)]` - it create tuples over the same indexes of the parts of the iterable you put into it.

---

By hand:

```
l = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] 


l2 = []
for colIdx in range(len(l[0])):  # 0-3 iterate over the inner indexes first
    newRow = []
    for rowIdx in range(len(l)): # 0-2 then over the outer ones 
        newRow.append(l[rowIdx][colIdx])
    l2.append(newRow)

print(l2)  # [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without built in functions? I think I'm not expected to do it with them. I dont quite understand Ubdus Samad's solution too

Comment: actually reading the comments made me think of simply applying a list comprehension instead of multiplication to get the size of list I want, then my code works. Could mutability of lists be a cause for repeated referencing? ( haven't rlly tried making a transpose function in tuple form, so food for thought)

My code:

    `def transpose(matrix):
        new_matrix=[[] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]
        for row in matrix:
        i=0
        for j in row:
            new_matrix[i]+=[j]
            i+=1
        return new_matrix`

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Learn the built-ins and list comprehensions, they make python fun. Edited answer for a "by hand" solution. Use a debugger to step through it to understand it. Read: [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth  The multiplication is what messes your code up this time, list comp is "a" solution - but still far longer then the `zip()` one

Comment: is there a way to learn the built in function? Dont understand what I'm reading by looking at help(zip) for eg

Comment: Is there a reason why multiplication messes up my code? Is it due to mutability? Do u have some common errors to watch out for when using mutable data structures? Pardon my questions as I just learnt this topic ytd

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth experiment:    `print( list(zip( [1,2,3],['a','b','c','d'], [100,200,300,400,500])))`

Comment: Common pitfalls:  global variables used in functions without declaring them `global` there - so in reality you use a new (scoped and soon forgotten) variable of the same name.  Using `list` or other datatype-names as variables and getting errors about `list(...)` not working. Using Mutable Datatypes that contain other mutables and trying to shallow copy `[:]` and wonder why they are not "distinct" afterwards.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth  If you are really curious, read the top 20-40 of [Top 50 ranked python questions (read the ones for python-3.6 as well ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) and try to memorize them, they are high ranked by reason.

Comment: *is there a way to learn the built in function?*, yes there should be, Python is open source, just go to it's Github repository and read about built-in stuff.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, will look up the new material

Answer (score 1):

What i meant was something like this:

```
def t(array): #The original array has size mxn
    duplicate = [[0 for x in range(len(array))] for y in range(len(array[1]))] #You create an array of size nxm, which is filled with zeros
    for i in range(len(array)): #Loop over the rows
        for j in range(len(array[i])): #Then loop over the columns
            duplicate[j][i] = array[i][j] #Replace j,i or duplicate with i,j th element of original
    return duplicate
```

Now,

```
>>> t([[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```